# PageRedirect issue in React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to redirect a page when user press link and it should redirect that page, but when user gets redirected the link button is still remain there only new page component is printed over there....

Here is code for App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import AboutUs from '/Users/yashchoksi/Documents/test/src/AboutUs.js';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Link to="/Users/yashchoksi/Documents/test/src/AboutUs.js">About Us</Link>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/Users/yashchoksi/Documents/test/src/AboutUs.js" component={AboutUs}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is code for AboutUs page:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Link,Switch,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
class AboutUs extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        Hello World.
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default AboutUs;
```

Now when my app load in browser and when user press link "About Us" it should remove that about us link and only shows what is on "AboutUs" page, but it also shows about us link also.

It shows something something like this:

[image]

Comment: Its behaviour of router that you are showing in screen shot

Comment: The answer is below, along with a *correct* online editor to show you how to fix it.

Comment: Can we pass fat arrow function directly in new component as you did it? It’s not compulsory to pass class ?

Comment: As matter of simplicity the function was in the same file but it doesn’t matter where you put it. If my answer helped be sure to mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

You have component layout in that way.Its not routing issue.

**Actually,`AboutUs` is a child component for `App` component.**

As `About us` link is within `App`
component and you also rendering `AboutUs` component in same `App` component. Because of this `About us` link not getting replaced.It will stay there.

```
 class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <Router>
            <div>
              <Link to="/Users/yashchoksi/Documents/test/src/AboutUs.js">About Us</Link>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/Users/yashchoksi/Documents/test/src/AboutUs.js" component={AboutUs}/>
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </Router>
        );
      }
    }
```

EDIT :
To  remove Link, make it part of some component rendering on different route.

e.g.

```
<Router> <div>
  <Switch>
    <Route
      path="/"
      exact
      render=
      {()=><Link to="/Users/yashchoksi/Documents/test/src/AboutUs.js">About Us</Link>} />

      <Route
      exact
      path="/Users/yashchoksi/Documents/test/src/AboutUs.js"
      component={AboutUs}/>
  </Switch>
</div>
</Router>
```

Comment: Then how to divide components for this problem?

Comment: @YashChoksi This Link working like Header /Sidebar menu for you if you checked your  attached screenshot. check EDIT

Answer (score 0):

The reason the link is *always* showing is because in your router you have a permanently placed link outside of your switch. If you don't want the About Us link to show you need to remove that from your `<Router></Router>`

Add another component in your router for the default route of '/' like so

```
  render() {
      return (
          <Router>
              <div>
                  <Switch>
                      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                      <Route path="/Users/yashchoksi/Documents/test/src/AboutUs.js" component={AboutUs}/>
                  </Switch>
             </div>
         </Router>
      );
 }
```

Then your home component can be

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';
const Home = () => <Link to="/Users/yashchoksi/Documents/test/src/AboutUs.js">About Us</Link>
```

Comment: If you find this answer helpful please mark as accepted. If you are unable to develop a fix for your issue with what is listed in my answer please ask your additional question below so long as it pertains to the original question.

Comment: Your implementation is wrong. Add 'exact' to the first route path and REMOVE exact from the second route path